# Page reload after http Exception in jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, jquery

I am bad in writting code but still i given my best of write it, Here i am trying to catch an http exception on my html page. So when ever an exception is found i just want to reload/refresh the page.

Please excuse me if this has solved earlier and provide me the right procedure

> var get_URL= window.content.location.href;
>     //console.log(get_URL);
>
> ```
>      jQuery.ajax({       
>         type: "POST",  
>         url: get_URL, 
>         //I doubt is this right way to call the get_URL variable??  
>         success: function(jqXHR, exception){  
>         alert("Exception Not Found");  
>         }, 
>        // Are my Parameters (jqXHR, exception) correct??  
>         error: function(jqXHR, exception) {  
>         alert("Exception Found");  
>             if (jqXHR.status === 0) {  
>                 alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');  
>             } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {  
>                 alert('Requested page not found. [404]');  
>             } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {  
>                 alert('Internal Server Error [500].');  
>             } else {  
>                 alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);  
>             }  
>             location.reload(true);  
>         }   
>       });
> ```

Any help will be highly Appreciated.

Comment: What doesn't work about it? It seems to be pretty solid from what I can see.

Comment: @StevenV Well when i am testing on exception side, my expected output is "Exception Found" but the above code results me "Exception Not Found".

Comment: If you're catching the exception on the server side, and just returning the string of text, that will return a HTTP 200 to jQuery. That will fire the `success` function, not the `error` function. If you want to do that, you need to change the HTTP status code on the server side to 500 to make jQuery fire the `error` function.

Comment: @StevenV I realized my problem, could you please help me how to catch the exception from server end. As i said i am not good in writing code.

Comment: @StevenV Guess achieved when i changed `jQuery.ajax` to `jQuery.ajaxSetup` and then started testing my code from `success` function i received my alert message _"Exception not Found"_ and next with `Error` function it thrown me an error _"Internal Server Error"_ Happy over here, Again tested my code from `success` function i received _"Exception"_ message :( May i know where am fault.